# Rails 5 trouble with belongs_to, when association model have custom table name.ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey Exception:PG::ForeignKeyViolation:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Rails 5, having trouble with belongs_to relationship, when association model have custom table name.

Below is the example

```
class Department < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'custom_departments'
end
```

```
class Request < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :department, class_name: 'Department', foreign_key: 'department_id', optional: true
end
```

When i try to save Request object it fails and getting the below error

```
request = Request.new(department_id: 1)
request.save

**ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey Exception:PG::ForeignKeyViolation:ERROR:insert or update on table "requests" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_8aaaf05eb8"
Key (department_id)=(1) is not present in table "departments".**
```

Thanks

Comment: do you have a department with ID = 1 already in custom_departments table?

Comment: Yes I have a row with id 1 in custom_departments table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look closely at the error message that you're getting from PostgreSQL (not Rails):

```
insert or update on table "requests" violates foreign key constraint
...
is not present in table "departments".*
```

You're have a problem with a foreign key constraint that references `departments` (not `custom_departments`) inside your PostgreSQL database. You originally created a `departments` table and had something like:

```
t.references :department, foreign_key: true
```

in a migration. Then later you changed your mind and switched to the `custom_departments` table but neglected to fix the foreign key in the database.

You need to drop the old FK (and probably the `departments` table) and add the new FK that references the right table in a migration:

```
def change
  remove_foreign_key :requests, :departments
  drop_table :departments # Assuming this is what you really want of course
  add_foreign_key :requests, :custom_departments, column: :department_id
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You are creating request for non existing department. You need to refer to existing object.

```
some_department = Department.all.first // get department you want to refer to 

request = Request.new 
request.department = some_department
request.save
```